# Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alpha4 - not picking .so libraries from local AAR

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I'm currently migrating my Android project to the latest version of the Android Gradle Plugin in order to use it with Android Studio 3.0.

Everything seems to be working fine except for the fact that .so native libraries files I have in a local AAR file are not packaged into the final APK. There is no `lib` folder inside it.

My project was already defining two flavor dimentions and I don't see any error or warning about it, so I think that's not the problem.

Android Gradle Plugin:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
```

Gradle version is `4.0`.

The local AAR is added using the `New Module...` option in Android Studio and it has always worked.

That's the `build.gradle` generated:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('FILENAME.aar'))
```

And in the application `build.gradle` I declare it as usual like this:

```
implementation project(':NAME_OF_THE_MODULE')
```

Am I missing a breaking change?
Is the following known issue related to my problem?
`While using this plugin with Android Studio, dependencies on local AAR files are not yet supported.`

**Update:** the old `flatDir` trick still works fine:

```
flatDir {
  dirs 'libs'
}
```

Then copy the AA inside that folder (i.e. `app/libs`) and declare it as a dependency in this way:

```
implementation(name: 'libvlc', ext: 'aar')
```

Comment: I opened a bug about it, hope it's resolved soon 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63055313

Answer (score 0):

in my case using "api" solved the problem.

instead of using:

`implementation(name: 'libvlc', ext: 'aar')`

use:

`api(name: 'libvlc', ext: 'aar')`

inside of build.gradle in your library project

And for more information see:

https://blog.mindorks.com/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html