# Android Gradle Plugin 3.6.2 - not picking .so libraries from local AAR

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have the same problem as described in [Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0-alpha4 - not picking .so libraries from local AAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785068/android-gradle-plugin-3-0-0-alpha4-not-picking-so-libraries-from-local-aar)

Only difference is the version of the android gradle plugin that is used,
including the .so-files from the aar worked in version 3.4.2, but it is not working in version 3.5.3 and 3.6.2.

As described in the other post I also tried importing the local project with the aar with api instead of implementation, also to no avail.